# ERROR string limit (1048576 bytes) reached

Tags: log-files, nxlog

I got some issue while working with my night batch log.

How push MULTIline log as one event?
I got stuck with one logfile that is over 26000 lines…

NxLog get stuck at some point - I don't really blame him- but how can I force him to work with those kind of multilines files?

My conf file:

```
<Extension json>
    Module      xm_json
</Extension>

<Extension multiline>
    Module      xm_multiline
    Exec        if $raw_event =~ /^\s*$/ drop();
    HeaderLine  /^\#\#\#$/
    EndLine     /\* CODE FIN JOB/
</Extension>

<Input in1>
    Module      im_file
    File        '/opt/XXX/YYYY/logs/*.nxlog'
    SavePos     FALSE
    ReadFromLast FALSE
    InputType   multiline
    Exec        if $raw_event =~ s/^\#\#\#\\n// {}
    Exec        $nxlog_message = $raw_event;
    Exec        $nxlog_tags = "YYYY";
    Exec        $nxlog_hostname = hostname();
    Exec        $nxlog_filename = file_name();
    Exec        file_remove($nxlog_filename);
    Exec        to_json();
</Input>
<Extension fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop
</Extension>
<Output logstash>
    Module      om_tcp
    Port        PPPP
    Host        ZZZZZZZ
</Output>
```

Here is some file that I push into nxlog.

Each file represent one job/event. The first one made NxLog freeze for all the weekend.

```
# find /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ -name "*.nxlog" -exec wc -l {} \;
26477 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
104 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
113 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
93 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
49 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
136 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
65 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
278 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
311 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
95 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
598 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
307 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
45 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
191 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
94 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
97 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
91 /opt/XXXX/YYYYY/logs/ZZZZZZ_WWWW.nxlog
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: hi,did you solve this? I also get this error..

Comment: Hey, you can increase the limit on the paid version. My temporary solution was to recompile from the source with an increased size.